# Is it possible to reuse existing test suite from OpenJDK to test new collection classes?

Tags: junit, java

I implemented a custom collection and want to test it by using unit-tests from open-jdk.
Is the test suite used to test the OpenJDK implementations open? Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Use the ones from Guava instead:

http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/testfw/com/google/common/collect/testing/

Comment: @thinker I think you should accept the answer